# How to click anchor, HTML tag, with VBS

Tags: html, vbscript, hyperlink, click, anchor

I have spent a lot of time to looking for for a solution for my problem without found it (Maybe I am only a newbie with VBS). 
So, my problem is: encapsulated into some #document, div, tab, table, tr, td, tbody, ul, li I have this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="EPCM.doNavigate('navurl://9378a638c45b5b365a39e30eb9f00ff6',0,'','null',1,'Tutti\x20gli\x20strumenti','');return false;" class="pgfsLiv3">Tutti gli strumenti</a>
```

I have tried to click this hyperlink using this VBScript:

```
Set a=oIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
  For i = 0 To a.Length - 1
    If a(i).innerText = "Strumenti di lavoro" Then a(i).Click
Next
```

It runs but it doesn't work (doesn't click the link). Any suggest?

Comment: I'm assuming the fact that your condition is `false` (the innertext of your example link is *not* "Strumenti di lavoro") is merely a mistake in typing up the question, and there are actually links where the innertext *is* "Strumenti di lavoro"?

Comment: Yes only a mistake in typing! with "Tutti gli strumenti" doesn't work too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clicking on innertext searched by class

```
For Each elem In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("pgfsLiv3")
   If elem.innerText = "Tutti gli strumenti" Then
       elem.focus
       elem.Click
   End If
Next
```

Comment: It Doesn't work.
I have tried whit this code

`Set box =  oIE.Document.getElementById("box")
   a(i) = box.GetElementsByTagName("a") 
   For i = 0 To a.length -1
    If a(i).innerText = "Tutti gli strumenti" Then
        a(i).focus
        a(i).Click
    End If
Next`

Comment: Because the HTML code is:

`<div id="box" style="width:100%">
<ul class="treenav">
<div style="width:100%; height: 20px; vertical-align: bottom;">...</div>  
<li>...</li>
<li>
<div class="pgfsRiga3" style="width: 100%">
<div>
<a href="#" onclick="EPCM.doNavigate('navurl://9378a638c45b5b365a39e30eb9f00ff6',0,'','null',1,'Tutti\x20gli\x20strumenti','');return false;" class="pgfsLiv3">Tutti gli strumenti</a>
</div>
<div class="pgfsFreccia3Dx">...</div>
</div>   
</li>
</ul>
</div>`

Comment: Try only focus, comment the click part in my code.  If the focus is set then the problem with link.

Comment: I have found a solution! It's inside a <iframe> so... this code run:
`Set box =  oIE.Document.getElementById("ivuFrm_page1ivu3").contentWindow.document.getElementById("box")
   Set a = box.getElementsbyTagName("a")
   
   For i = 0 To a.length -1
    If a(i).innerText = "Tutti gli strumenti" Then
        a(i).focus
        a(i).Click
    End If
Next`